# Transfer data from multiple workbooks into Master workbook in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to run a macro, in an Excel document that copies values in standardised time-sheets (Other Excel Documents) and pastes them into my original macro enabled spreadsheet (Zmaster file), in SharePoint.

The code works in my local drive but not when the master file and all other time-sheet spreadsheets are in SharePoint.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String
Filepath = "//hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test RESTRICTED Access"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    If MyFile = "Zmaster.xlsx" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("A59:AF59").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 35))

    MyFile = Dir

Loop

Range("D1").Select
MsgBox "Process is Complete!"

End Sub
```

In the Zmaster document in SharePoint, I get the "Process is Complete" message without anything being transferred.

Comment: Where you use `erow = Sheet1.Cells ....`, that should be `erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells .....`

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you, I did not receive a notification and was unaware you'd posted until now. I'm still stuck on this code despite implementing your suggestion which is now driving me crazy. The error message I receive is Run time error '52' Bad file or number with the MyFile = Dir(Filepath) highlighted yellow when I debug.

Comment: Sorry just tried it again and it makes no difference I still get the "Process is complete" message without anything actually happening. One thing to note is that I have tried to open excel files in that location using VBA and I have not been able to..There are no permissions set or user restrictions with regards to accessing any of the files in this location

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem was the way you wrote the address. So I added three `Replace()` lines that will amend your address if you are trying to access it online. As I am not sure where the location of the folder you are looking for is or have access to it, please apply some judgement whether to rewrite your address or use the code below.

I have tested the code below with a folder path in my SharePoint and on my local hard drive and it can access it and loop through the directory.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow As Long
Dim Filepath As String

'Your folder address
Filepath = "//hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test RESTRICTED Access/"

'Amend address
    Filepath = Replace(Filepath, "/", "\")
    Filepath = Replace(Filepath, "https:", "")
    Filepath = Replace(Filepath, " ", "%20")

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Zmaster.xlsx" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)

    'Put your copy paste code here

    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Range("D1").Select
MsgBox "Process is Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me Genie, I really appreciate your input. I now get a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Open' of Object 'Workbooks' failed and when I debug I see the  Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile) line highlighted yellow. I sense that were pretty close but I'm not quite over the line, I'm convinced it centres around the filepath as when I run the macro from my local drive it works...Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Your correct in saying that my address is online, and the folder is located in a document library within SharePoint which you do not have access to. The complete address is https://hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet%20Test%20%20RESTRICTED%20Access/Forms/AllItems.aspx  As that address is not compatible with my code I have used the 'Open with explorer' option to obtain the following path https://hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test  RESTRICTED Access  in my code which you see above. Hopefully that's some more context which will help with my query.

Comment: Two observations:

1. On your link ( hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test RESTRICTED Access ) you do not have a backslash at the end. It should be ( hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test RESTRICTED Access/ ).

2. Alternatively if that does not make a difference, go to your SharePoint, right click on the link and select properties. You should be able to see the exact path to the file you are looking for and verify that there are no typos in what you have written.

Comment: I'd actually had the backslash at the end of my code so 1. didn't make a difference. There doesn't seem to be a typo in the path to my files as confirmed by the following https://hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet%20Test%20%20RESTRICTED%20Access/Forms/AllItems.aspx Maybe there is another way to solve this. I'm correctly looking at storing all the files in an array and running my code against that array to copy values and paste into my Zmaster file but in typically novice fashion I'm struggling with that too

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post the closest thing to an answer I have, the below code runs and works but for only the first file it sees in the folder and pastes the values into the Zmaster file.

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow As Long
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Filepath2 As String
'Your folder address
Filepath = "//hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test  RESTRICTED Access/"

'Amend address
Filepath = Replace(Filepath, "/", "\")
Filepath = Replace(Filepath, "https:", "")
Filepath = Replace(Filepath, " ", "%20")

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "Zmaster.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Filepath2 = "https://hub.bcu.ac.uk/sites/rie/cdc-work-area/Timesheet Test  RESTRICTED Access/"
Workbooks.Open (Filepath2 & MyFile)

Range("A59:AF59").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 35))

MyFile = Dir

Loop

Range("D1").Select
MsgBox "Process is Complete!"

End Sub
```

Any Idea how to get this into a loop so that it picks up all the files now. After 10 days and endless sleepless nights I see light at the end of the tunnel.

Thanks for your help again Genie